# how do i resolve WordPress website white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

Today i tried to upload my local website created on XAMPP to the live server but after uploading and configuration of the DB, I'm facing a white screen issue, after some research i released that the problem on my theme when i activated the debugger (define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );) im recieving this msg :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function appcloud_option() in /home/groupe/public_html/wp-content/themes/appcloud/header.php on line 27**

the problem is on my localhost everything seems to be fine.

```html
<?php

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">

    <!--preloder start here-->
    <?php 
        if( appcloud_option('appcloud_display_preloader') == '1' && appcloud_option('appcloud_display_preloader') != '' ) { 
        $preloader_image = appcloud_option('appcloud_preloader_image_up');
        $preloader_image = $preloader_image['url'];
    ?>
    <div id="preloader" <?php if( $preloader_image != '' ){ ?>style="background-image: url( <?php echo esc_url($preloader_image); ?> );"<?php } ?>></div>
    <?php } ?>


    <!--preloder end here-->
    
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
         <div class="<?php if( appcloud_option('appcloud_sticky_menu_active') == '1'){ echo esc_attr('heading_nav'); } else{ echo esc_attr('general_heading_nav'); } ?>">
            <div class="container-fluid">
             
                    <div class="<?php if( appcloud_option('appcloud_sticky_menu_active') == '1'){ echo esc_attr('nav-bg navbar-fixed-top'); } else{ echo esc_attr('navbr-bg'); } ?>" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e('Toggle navigation', 'appcloud'); ?></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <?php if( function_exists('appcloud_logo')){ appcloud_logo(); } ?>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <?php if( function_exists('appcloud_main_menu')){ appcloud_main_menu(); } ?>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: more information is needed. Looks like you are missing something on server, but it is difficult to help you if we don't see header.php etc.

Comment: i tried to downgrade and upload the theme files again and now im receiving a new msg : Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress. also i attached the header file to my post

Comment: I am now WP dev, but as I understand you are missing some plugin that provides `appcloud_option` function

Comment: hey Justinas, the thing is with the same files the website works just fine on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i just fixed the problem it appears the i had some kind of issue in my theme folder i uploaded the child theme again and made my modifications and everything is alright now.
thx for your help guys.